# Is there a way 'at all' to 'skip 'complete action using' in Android

Tags: android

We have an application in which we need to exit the activity and launch the home screen, when the user performs an action.

The action can be performed via multiple inputs (i.e., from multiple activities), as well through hardware buttons.

What we do is the standard way of launching home.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(startMain);
```

What happens here is, the launchers are shown with 'Complete action using ... ' message.

**It is very critical for security purposes that, this'complete action using ...' dialog is not shown** , but we navigate directly to home using the launcher the app was started with.

**Note :**

We even tried using 'packageManager.clearPackagePreferredActivities' & adding one of the activites that listens on CATEGORY_HOME, ACTION_MAIN intents.

But no luck there, as the android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission is not available for the versions we support (>= Gingerbread).

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which launcher you want to use, simply add:

```
startMain.setPackage( "your.package.name" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks 323go, for the setPackage part. The code below works like a charm !

```
private void goHome() {
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<android.content.pm.ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(homeIntent, 0);
    String className = activities.get(0).activityInfo.taskAffinity;

    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startMain.setPackage(className);
    context.startActivity(startMain);
    ((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

Comment: Just to be safe, you might want to check for `(activities.count()>0)` before getting the class name, and also make sure the `className` has a value.